# Combining several ContextMenu items into one

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to combine several ContextMenu items into one. Currently, I am using separate MenuItem for it to work. Is there a way to combine all these MenuItems into one WHILE being able to control each of these event triggers when the users click on the different MenuItems?

```
NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();


        System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem ChangeDetailsMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
        ChangeDetailsMenu.Text = "Change Contact Details";
        ChangeDetailsMenu.Click += ChangeContactDetails;

        System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem ChangeKinectAngleMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
        ChangeKinectAngleMenu.Text = "Change Kinect Angle";
        ChangeKinectAngleMenu.Click += ChangeKinectAngle;

        System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem exitMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
        exitMenu.Text = "Exit";
        exitMenu.Click += ExitHandler;

        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(exitMenu);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(ChangeDetailsMenu);
        contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(ChangeKinectAngleMenu);

        Icon icon = new Icon("kse.ico");
        notifyIcon.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
        notifyIcon.Icon = icon;
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

private void ExitHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }



    private void ChangeContactDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ChangeKinectAngle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? can you help us with a use case. Maybe there could be alternative cleaner solution?

Comment: I am creating a TaskBar ContextMenu that allows the user to right click on the icon and choose different functions. The code above does just that but it's too lengthy and I wish to make it as short as possible.